# cambiar coordenadas x,y de un item tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

He logrado aceder a un hijo especifico de Canvas

```
def actualizarNumeros(self):
    for i in self.tela.find_withtag("numero"):
        # Capture todos los items que contienen numeros
        # procedo a tomar el item i y asignarlo a donde corresponde x,y
        for xy in self.tablero:
            if str(xy[0]) == str(self.tela.itemcget(i, 'text')):
                pass
                #self.tela.itemconfig(i, padx=0)
```

Dicho hijo tiene coordenadas x,y ya que fue creado asi:

```py
self.tela.create_text(i[1]+50, i[2]+50, text=str(i[0]), tags="numero")
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿a travez de "itemconfig" como puedo modificar x, y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes hacer esto mediante `itemconfig`, los argumentos disponibles para tu caso (`Text`) son:

> activefill, activestipple, anchor, angle, disabledfill, disabledstipple, fill, font, justify, offset, state, stipple, tags, text, underline, width

Puedes ver dichas opciones (argumentos posibles para `itemconfig`) simplemente llamando al método sin ningún argumento, lo que retorna un diccionario con cada opción como clave.

```
print(self.tela.itemconfig(i))
```

Para mover un item usa:

- **`canvas.coords(tagOrId, x0, y0, x1, y1, ..., xn, yn)`**: permite mover un item pasando sus nuevas coordenadas. El número de coordenadas depende de cada item. 
  Si solo se la pasa la id o etiqueta del item retorna una tupla con las coordenadas actuales del mismo.

  Para mover tu item  `Text` a una nueva posición, simplemente debes hacer:

  ```
  self.tela.coords(i, nueva_x, nueva_y)
  ```
- **`canvas.move(tagOrId, xAmount, yAmount)`**: el cual mueve el item especificado por id o tag pasado como primer argumento, incrementando `xAmount` su posición en el eje `x` e incrementando `yAmount` en el eje `y`.

  Es decir, si tienes un item en posición `(x=5, y=3)`, 
  `canvas.move(item, 2, 1)` mueve el item a la posición `(x=7, y=4)`.